# My wallet doesn't show a confirmed transaction

Tags: transactions, wallet-notify

Someone sent me Bitcoin payment but when I check my wallet nothing appears. On the blockchain, the transaction is already confirmed.

I use archived address.

Comment: What wallet software are you using? What is an "archived address"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your btc wallet using app then go to addresses ! click on the address that you want to recover the and hope des :D